# What is the meaning of "up and kicking"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "up and kicking"?
Is it similar to "up and running", but with the former one describing people and the latter one describing machines?
Thank you!

Comment: Where did you come across it? More details would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be used when describing someone who has been sick in bed for some time, but is now feeling better and is out of bed and back to some of their usual activities.  "Joe was laid out in bed for 2 months, but now he's up and kicking."

Answer (score 2):

"Up and kicking" is an idiom referring to a recovery of some form. Its more common form is *alive* and kicking:

> [alive and kicking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/alive+and+kicking) — Alive and alert; living and healthy. [It] originally was used by fishmongers hawking their wares to convince customers of their freshness and has been considered a cliché since about 1850. The variant originated in the 1960s as a denial of someone's reported death.
>
> John's completely recovered; he's alive and kicking.